# How can I return more than one value through function in C?

Tags: c

I have been asked in an interview how one can return more than one value from function. I have answered saying by using pointers we can achieve(call by reference) this in C. Then he told me he is looking for some other way of returning more than one value. I said we can return a struct object but here also he didn't seem to be impressed.

I would like to know others ways to return more than one value from a function.

I have seen this questions being asked here on SO, but could not find anything C specific.

Comment: Unless the interviewer wanted arrays (but then only values of the same type can be returned) structs and pointers is the only way to return multiple values.

Comment: Just because the interviewer didn't seem impressed with your answer of returning a struct (with multiple values inside) doesn't mean it is not a good answer.  Yes there are other ways but for C the **return** of a struct is a good answer.  It would be nice if you could "return" an array, but in C the best you can do is return a pointer, unlike C++ where you can return `std::vector`.

Comment: "didn't seem to be impressed"... just not impressed, or did he tell you that you were plain wrong and had not answered his question?

Comment: By saying "didn't seem to be impressed" i mean he was keep on saying i want a way that is not in textbooks.

Comment: *"I want a way that is not in textbooks"* sounds like a warning bell to me.

Comment: probably he was nitpicking that you denoted the _call by pointer_ a _call by reference_ :]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The tricky problem is that the interviewer has some solution they are particularly happy with in mind and they are likely grading you by whether you have the same clever trick as them or not.

You could just name a few ways such as you did, and still not fall upon their secret trick.  And if you knew their secret trick, you could well not be impressed with it.

So in these situations, its to turn it from interview into conversation.  Once you detect you're not moving towards their ego, you can avoid heading towards the intimidating "I don't know" "I give up" and instead try out the "so do you have any clever solution?  Is there an in-house recipe for this at Xyz Inc?" etc.

Any glimpse at their obviously self-impressed solution and you are back on firm ground where you can talk about it and ask them if they have thought about various factors that come to mind and basically interview them.

Everyone loves a good listener, and getting them to talk about their tricks is a good way to get them to leave the interview throughly impressed with you! ;)

Comment: Excellent answer.  Always realize that a technical interview is not only about technical topics.

Comment: At interviews it's very important to ask questions back to clarify things, to turn abstract and vague questions/tasks into concrete answerable/doable ones. Likewise, you may be find yourself dealing with too hard restrictions and at that moment it's a good thing to think and ask if they can be relaxed, maybe at some other expense. The worst thing is to make wrong assumptions and be unable to give a good or any answer because of that. If the interviewer refuses to provide details, you can enumerate possibilities and work them out independently. It will show your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

1. Return value using the return statement (as you already know)
2. Return via references.
3. Return values via the heap.
4. Return values via global variables.

Comment: but how using return statement i can return more than one value??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: the interviewer likely meant a general kind of "returning" something because in C you can return directly only one value with `return`.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you consider *a value*. If a value is a piece of information for you, *more values* could be a struct of values. More values could be also passed via pointers or arrays, even a `char*` containing a list of (non-zero alphanumerical) *values*. If you consider a value to be a bit of information a single returned `uint32_t` may hold 32 *values*. You could even mess around with signals or sockets or pipes or files.

But for you do not even know the use case and the requirements it imposes on the solution, it's indeed a rather hard task to come up with *the* right solution (and you actually *did* come up with some proper solutions ...).

Answer (score 0):

Return a pointer to a structure, or pack several small datatypes into one large datatype, or use global variables.
The first is probably the cleanest way to do it, the other two might have their uses in certain situations.

If we pass the address instead of the true value of the parameters.
Then whenever we refer those parameters we do it with the address.

Answer (score 0):

returning a pointer to structure is the suitable answer.(Obviously, the objective of the program can decide what's the best that can be done). The interviewer might have wanted you to say 'I don't know' which would have shown your lack of confidence in the field. I think you provided good solutions, though not what he had in his mind. You could have asked him about a typical scenario where he wanted multiple values to be returned and then discuss how struct-pointer is a reasonable alternative.