# How to return multiple values and store them in main() function?

Tags: c, function, return-value

I want to return two or more values from a function and want to store those values into the `main()` function. I'm trying to do this by following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, s, p;
    printf("Enter tow numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    p = function(num1, num2);
    s = function(num1, num2);
    printf("Sum is: %d\nProduct is: %d", p, s);
    return 0;
}

int function(int x, int y)
{
    int sum, product;
    sum = x+y;
    product = x*y;
    return product, sum;
}
```

If I enter two numbers, say `5 2` I want my result to be:

```
Sum is: 7
Product is: 10
```

But I'm getting 7 for both.  How can I get my desired output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning multiple values from a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104789/returning-multiple-values-from-a-method)

Comment: maybe a better candidate for a duplicate is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253489/how-can-i-return-more-than-one-value-through-function-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not permit you to define a function which returns multiple types or multiple instances of a single type.  You can however bundle variables of similar or disparate types together into a new user-defined type using a [struct](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson7.html).  In this case, you would do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
    int sum;
    int product;
} myStruct;

myStruct function(int x, int y) {
    myStruct val;
    val.sum = x+y;
    val.product = x*y;
    return val;
}

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    myStruct result;
    printf("Enter tow numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    result = function(num1, num2);
    printf("Sum is: %d\nProduct is: %d", result.sum, result.product);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, while your program above is syntactically correct, the `,` in the return of your function has the result of only returning the last value in the collection of comma separated values.  Normally the `,` isn't used in conjunction with a `return`; it can be quite handy when used in a `for` loop however.

Comment: You can bundle any types together in a struct, I'm not sure what you mean by "atomic".

Comment: You could also return an array of ints

Comment: Thank you. Now I can return multiple values using structure.

Comment: Re: 'atomic' type. I was trying to just refer to any of the native C types.  I didn't mean to exclude user-defined types, arrays, or pointers, though I can see how somebody could have inferred that meaning.  I've edited for clarity.

Comment: `function` has no prototype and it'll be assumed to return `int`. You should move it to before `main` or declare a prototype

Comment: sorry but I didn't see it fixed

Comment: Hadn't pressed 'save'.  Should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to expect the product and sum values on arguments, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int x, int y, int *p, int *s);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, s, p;
    printf("Enter tow numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    function(num1, num2, &p, &s);
    printf("Sum is: %d\nProduct is: %d", s, p);
    return 0;
}

void function(int x, int y, int *p, int *s)
{
    *s = x+y;
    *p = x*y;
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the address of s and p to the function and the values of num1 and num2?

Comment: Yes @shahid , it's way similar to what happens on _scanf_ when you read num1 and num2. This way we can "write directly" on s and p